# How to configure Twitter Bootstrap for not offset blocks?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I set variable value using AngularJS.

```
<div class="col-md-5">Cost:</div>
<div class="col-md-7">{{ cost }}</div>
<div class="col-md-5">Total:</div>
<div class="col-md-7">{{ total }}</div>
```

And I see

```
Cost:  5
Total: 7
```

But when `cost = ""`, I see:

```
Cost:  Total:
7
```

But I want to see:

```
Cost:
Total: 7
```

How to configure my HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you could simply add a line break?

`<br />`

Either that or you could write a script that would test the value of the cost. Why would the cost be = to "" anyway? Surely to have the total there would be a cost?

Try setting the cost = " ", with the space inbetween.

You could also use php I suppose.

Comment: While adding a `br` element will work it's not really a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your line into `div.row`, like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-5">Cost:</div>
  <div class="col-xs-7">{{cost}}</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-5">Total:</div>
  <div class="col-xs-7">{{total}}</div>
</div>
```

So now when you will not have value of your model you will still can see your labels in 1 line.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/kSvv1EjXyB7qhXotNEA7?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can do here. First you should be starting a new `row` element for each row of data, like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">Cost:</div>
    <div class="col-md-7"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">Total:</div>
    <div class="col-md-7">{{ total }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The next thing you can do is either add `&nbsp` to your div content

```css
.col-md-5 { background-color: red; }
.col-md-7 { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<h5>Example 1:</h5>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">Cost:</div>
    <div class="col-md-7"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">Total:</div>
    <div class="col-md-7">{{ total }}</div>
  </div>
</div>

<h5>Example 2:</h5>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">Cost:</div>
    <div class="col-md-7">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">Total:</div>
    <div class="col-md-7">{{ total }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use span if you want elements to be inline instead of div. Wrap your inline elements inside a div of complete length

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <span class="col-md-5">Cost:</span>
     <span class="col-md-7">{{ cost }}</span>
</div>

<div class ="col-md-12">
    <span class="col-md-5">Total:</span>
    <span class="col-md-7">{{ total }}</span>
</div>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11572/

P.S : change the value of cost and test it.